# Support for Multilingual feature using Adaptive Cards in Microsoft Bot framework

Tags: bots

I am testing the Multilingual Bot downloaded from Microsoft bot framework. While doing so, some of my content are not getting translated.

[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFqtt.png)

You can see the following code where I have inserted few lines that asks the user if there is anything I can help ? This gets translated in to tthe language selected by the User. But, the content in CardAction() object Title 'Yes' and 'No' are not getting translated.

How to handle such translations in the middleware ?

```
bool translate = userLanguage != TranslationSettings.DefaultLanguage;
if (IsLanguageChangeRequested(turnContext.Activity.Text))
{
    await _accessors.LanguagePreference.SetAsync(turnContext, turnContext.Activity.Text);
    var reply = turnContext.Activity.CreateReply($"Your current language code is: {turnContext.Activity.Text}");
    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);
    await _accessors.UserState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);

    // This content is getting partially translated.
    var newRply = turnContext.Activity.CreateReply("Is there anything else I can help you with?"); 
    newRply.SuggestedActions = new SuggestedActions()
    {
        Actions = new List<CardAction>()
        {
        // The title is not getting translated
        new CardAction() { Title = "Yes", Type = ActionTypes.PostBack, Value = Spanish },
        // The title is not getting translated
        new CardAction() { Title = "No", Type = ActionTypes.PostBack, Value = English },
        },
    };
    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(newRply);
}
    else
{
    var reply = turnContext.Activity.CreateReply("Choose your language:");
    reply.SuggestedActions = new SuggestedActions()
    {
        Actions = new List<CardAction>()
        {
            new CardAction() { Title = "Español", Type = ActionTypes.PostBack, Value = Spanish },
            new CardAction() { Title = "English", Type = ActionTypes.PostBack, Value = English },
        },
    };

    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply);
    }
}
```

Expecting that string in the CardAction() should also be translated into the language chosen by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using Microsoft Translator class that comes with the Sample. From the same sample, I implemented  a new class (MultilingualCardAction) by inheriting CardAction class.

This works for me but there may be better ways as well.

```
public class MultilingualCardAction : CardAction
{
private readonly MicrosoftTranslator _translator;

    private string _language;
    public MultilingualCardAction(string language)
    {
        _language = language;
        _translator = new MicrosoftTranslator(<<YOUR TRANSLATION KEY>>);
    }

    public string cardTitle
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Title;
        }

        set
        {
            this.Title = getTranslatedText(value).Result;
        }
    }
    async Task<string> getTranslatedText(string title)
    {
        return await _translator.TranslateAsync(title, _language);
    }
}
```

Then I created the CardAction object this way.

```
var newRply = turnContext.Activity.CreateReply("Is there anything else I can help you with?");
newRply.SuggestedActions = new SuggestedActions()
{
     Actions = new List<CardAction>()
     {
          new MultilingualCardAction('es') { cardTitle = "Yes", Type = ActionTypes.PostBack, Value = "Yes" },
          new MultilingualCardAction('es') { cardTitle = "No, thanks!", Type = ActionTypes.PostBack, Value = "No" },
      },
 };
 await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(newRply);
```

Refer the image below.

[image]